# Numpy fast iterations over np.where() indices in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization

I have a grid array full of True and False values, and I want to iterate only over the True values.

```
indices = list(zip(*np.where(grid)))
for iterat in range(I):
    print(f"Calculation stream function... {iterat}/{I}")
    for i, j in indices:
        psi[i, j] = 0.25 * (psi[i-1, j] + psi[i+1, j] + psi[i, j-1] + psi[i, j+1])
```

Unfortunately this is taking too long, this is for a CFD simulation of incompressible flow over bodies, and for psi matrix of 400x300 (I only index about 4/5 of the positions) and I = 10000 it is taking around 60-80 minutes to complete.

Is there a faster way to do this loop?

Comment: use np.select and then make np.where(grid) as your condition

Comment: Like np.select([np.where(grid)], choice)? How can I express the sum of the adjacent values in the choice argument? psi[i,j] = 0.25 * (psi[i-1, j] + ...)

Comment: make a full working example - will be easier to help you optimize

Comment: Your iterative code could have problems if there are `True` values close to the `grid` edge.  It could also produce different results when there are adjacent `True` values, where one iteration modifies values used by the next.

Comment: Yes I know, luckily in my case edges are all False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `np.select` is your best choice here.

The following snippet runs in a few seconds on my laptop.

```py
import numpy as np

I = 10_000
shape = (400, 300)

# Define sample data
grid = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=shape, dtype=bool)
psi = np.random.random(size=shape)

# Iterate
for iterat in range(I):
    print(f"Calculation stream function... {iterat}/{I}")
    new_psi = 0.25 * (
        np.roll(psi, 1, axis=0)
        + np.roll(psi, -1, axis=0)
        + np.roll(psi, 1, axis=1)
        + np.roll(psi, -1, axis=1)
    )
    # Use new_psi when grid = True, psi otherwise
    psi = np.select([grid], [new_psi], psi)
```

Comment: noticed that it won't produce the same result. In the OP's code, one adjacent value could be modified before the computation of the next one.

Comment: Oh that's right. Not sure though which version is the one the OP really wants

Comment: Both work, the result doesn't really change over so many iterations. Thanks a lot!! Didn't know about using np.roll to vectorize computations.